# Question about ListPlot of variables

Tags: plotting, variable-definitions, variable

My question is trivial but I don't seem to be able to get the answer.

Suppose that I do a numerical computation (division of some numbers that come from the numerical solution of an NDSolve or something else) and I want to assign them in a variable so that I can use it latter for plotting, e.g.
`p1=Abs[...]`.
The output of the p1 is 
`p1={0.005}`
with brackets something that it makes it impossible to do the following plotting:
`ListPlot[{1,p1}]`
any idea what is happening and why it is happening?

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps `ListPlot[{1,p1[[1]]}]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's true, this way it is correctly plotted, but I don't get why this happens (or it has to happen that way). Could you help?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you show your code. Probably you don't want to use ListPlot for plotting only one point?

Comment: No of course not. I will try to sketch what it does because it is a long one.
`NDSolve[...,as]` which `as` is the variable in the differential equation. Now I do the following assignement:
`p1=as[30]`
and the output is `{0.005}`. Then I do it for a different value
`p2=as[40]` and the output is `{0.004}`. And this is the point that I get confused. Why the p1,p2,..etc come with brackets. Also this makes the `ListPlot` impossible unless I use `p1[[1]]`. Firstly, why? Secondly, is there a way to avoid it? Thirdly, what do the `[[]]` mean? Thank you very much!

Comment: See `First` and `Part` in the documentation. The reason the list appears is because many `Solve` functions can acquire multiple solutions. In this case, the number of solutions is 1, so the length of the list is 1. You can instruct _Mathematica_ to only use the first (and in this case only) solution by taking the appropriate part.

Comment: Yeah I got that digging up online. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Hal!. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake easily found in the documentation. It's good that you asked, and even better that you got your answer, but leaving this here forever it's unlikely to help any future visitors in the long term, so it may become a candidate for deletion. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NDSolveValue is an easy possibility to solve your problem:

```
sol = NDSolveValue [{x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 5}]
pi = Table[{t, sol[t]}, {t, 0, 5, .25 }]
ListPlot[pi]
```

[image]

Of course you can also plot continuously

```
Plot[sol[t],{t,0,5}]
```